# Is there something like a sub-desktop, or a set of windows in XMonad?

Tags: window-manager, xmonad

When working on different tasks on a project, I have a very similar setup for each task: On a free desktop I Open a terminal window, an editor and a debugging window. Can I manage such a set as one block? Perhaps as a set of windows inside a window? For example I'd like to be able to move the whole set to another desktop at once. Or to create such a block by running a script.

Comment: I'm not sure, but could it be that [Groups](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Groups.html) is what you're looking for? Or maybe [SubLayouts](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-SubLayouts.html)?

Comment: @Bobby Thanks, it looks that one of these things will be just what I need.